# Android change package name errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I've clone a copy of Rocket Chat Android app, I'm trying to customize it and I need to change the package name.

I have followed this steps: [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)
and now I'm getting the next error whenever I try to run the project.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':rocket-chat-core:compileKotlin'.
>   Compilation error. See log for more details

Log itself has no extra information. Also Android Studio is showing me an "cannot resolve symbol R" error.

I've already tried to Rebuild Project without any changes. Also didn't find too much information about the error.

Anybody? Thx

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40638290/4726718. Follow the 3 steps.

Answer (score 2):

There should be same package name in two places:

1. Gradle - Check application id.
2. Manifest - Check the package name.

If both are same. Go to your project directory and delete the `build` folder and delete the another `build` directory under app folder.

Now click `Invalid Caches/Restart` in the file tab.

Check the every class file having the new package name in the `R` file import statement.

Hope it helps:)